# Skipping instructions during interactive python debug session

Tags: python, pdb

I was wondering if it is possible to skip an instruction while in an interactive debugging session. Suppose I'm debugging the following code

```
action_1()
time.sleep(60)
action_2()
```

If I'm at `action_1()`, I will have to wait a minute to get to `action_2()`. What I would like is a way to tell the debugger to skip the next instruction without executing it.
I tried looking it up on google, but nothing useful came up.

It is possible to come up with quick and dirty workarounds, like commenting out the sleep instruction, or wrapping it with an if statement, but they are cumbersome and error prone. I'm looking for a more elegant solution.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe you want the [Jump command](https://docs.python.org/2/library/pdb.html) in PDB:

> j(ump) lineno
>
> Set the next line that will be executed. Only available in the
>   bottom-most frame. This lets you jump back and execute code again, or
>   jump forward to skip code that you don’t want to run.
>
> It should be noted that not all jumps are allowed — for instance it is
>   not possible to jump into the middle of a for loop or out of a finally
>   clause.